# Angular ngRepeat not preserving order of Firebase priority items?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase

Pretty new to Angular & Firebase here, but noticed an odd behavior querying and presenting ordered data that isn't addressed anywhere else yet...

I'm pushing data to firebase and setting priority with a descending negative value so that newest data is on top of the list.

When retrieving the ref with `child_added` events, I can confirm the data is arriving in the correct order; however, when used with ngRepeat, the data is somehow getting reversed (newest data appears on bottom of ngRepeat list).

If I use something like `.append()` the data is correctly ordered. But would rather do it the 'Angular' way with ngRepeat.

```
// example html binding
// ====================================
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(itemID, item) in list">{{itemID}}</li>
</ul>


// example controller code
// ====================================
var laApp = angular.module('laApp', ['firebase']);

laApp.controller('laAppCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://ngrepeatbug.firebaseio.com');

    $scope.pushPriority = function(){
        var uid = new Date().getTime();
        var priority = 0 - uid;
        // set with -priority so newest data on top
        ref.push().setWithPriority(uid, priority);
    }

    $scope.list = {};
    ref.orderByPriority().on('child_added', function(snap){
        $timeout(function(){
            var snapID = snap.key();
            var snapVal = snap.val();

            //repeat method
            $scope.list[snapID] = snap.val();

            //append method
            $('ul.append').append("<li>" + snapVal + "</li>")
        })
    })
});
```

Pen comparing ngRepeat and append methods:
http://codepen.io/juddam/pen/dIiLz

I've read other solutions that either convert the `$scope.list` object into an array that is then used with $filter or reversing order on client, but this defeated the whole purpose of storing data by priority and having a straightforward method for querying and presenting ordered data.

Know orderByPriority is new to firebase v2.0 so wondering if bug or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Objects in javascript have no set key order, so there is no way to guarantee which key will be displayed before another without putting them into an array and sorting it.

Comment: Thanks Zack - I was aware, but since the display order was consistently in reverse order thought might be missing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the children to an object with this:

```
 $scope.list[snapID] = snap.val();
```

Even though this looks like you're adding to an array, you're actually adding to a regular object. And as @ZackArgyle says in his comment: the keys in an object have no guaranteed order.

If you want to maintain the order of the items, you should push them into an array.

```
 $scope.list.push(snap.val());
```

This adds them with numeric indices, which will maintain their order.

If you want to both maintain the order of the items **and** their key, you will have to manage them in an array.

```
 $scope.list.push({ $id: snap.key(), value: snap.val() });
```

That last approach is an extremely simplified version of what AngularFire does when you call `$asArray()`.

Comment: Additionally, the method is ignoring prevChild. The items arriving from the server also have no guaranteed order. So when using child_added, it is also important to observe prevChild to determine where they go in the array. Another feature of AngularFire's bindings.

Comment: @Kato Good point. In this context though using `orderByPriority()` and `child_added` for initial view load. So if received a later `child_added` event will have to observe prevChild.

Comment: Thanks @Frank - would upvote but not enough cred :) This was part of a larger service that would collate denormed firebase data. I am using AngularFire elsewhere, but [read `$asArray()` will download all data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html). Since I'm using it to manage and render image data, was worried about overloading the browser.